# Is there a way to identify the const modifier of the variable in run-time?

Tags: c++, rtti

What I mean is the following question.
Then I try to know the type and the constancy of the `const` pointer using `typeinfo` library, we get them both:

```
int* pY1 = 0;
const int* pY2 = 0;
std::cout << "pY1: " << typeid(pY1).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << "pY2: " << typeid(pY2).name() << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
pY1: int *
pY2: int const *
```

But then I try the following

```
int x1 = 0;
const int x2 = 0;   
std::cout << " x1: " << typeid(x1).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << " x2: " << typeid(x2).name() << std::endl;
```

an output is

```
x1: int
x2: int
```

[ideone code](http://ideone.com/Gej5qO)
Is it possible to recognise the constant in the runtime? If yes, how to do this?

Comment: RTTI is Run Time Type Information; but you already have all information at *compile* time here, encoded in the static type of the variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using C++11 you don't need rtti at all, you can use [std::is_const](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const) example :

```
int x1 = 0;
const int x2 = 0;
bool is_x1_const = std::is_const<decltype(x1)>::value;
bool is_x2_const = std::is_const<decltype(x2)>::value;
```

Old C++ version :

```
template<typename T> bool is_const(T) { return false;}
template<typename T> bool is_const(const T) { return true;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using C++11 now. But thank you anyway.

Comment: It can be implemented easily in C++03

Comment: `decltype` will be a problem, though.

Comment: Well, using a function loses the compile-time goodies, however it will still be faster than using rtti anyway.

Comment: An old C++ version related decision looks like a hack, but it's so elegant :) Thank you!

Comment: It's not a hack at all, this kind of idiom is standard practice and well-defined by the standard.

Answer (score 4):

Take the address, and you are back to your working case:

```
int x1 = 0;
const int x2 = 0;
std::cout << " x1: " << typeid(&x1).name( ) << std::endl;
std::cout << " x2: " << typeid(&x2).name( ) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

At runtime there is no concept of constness. This is something that is used only at compile-time, which gives you the benefit of knowing constness earlier than you envision it.

If you don't have C++11 available for `std::is_const`, you can still copy an implementation and deduce constness with template specialization. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const for an example implementation.

```
template<class T> struct is_const          : std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct is_const<const T> : std::true_type {};
```

You could do something similar with a function instead of a type as well, but you lose the compile-time aspect of the logic.